# Why is Windows 'Run:' different from CMD line?

Tags: windows, shell

When I type 'http://www.google.com at the Windows Run: prompt it launches my default browser.

But when I do it at the CMD or Commnad prompt it does not. I assume that there is some form of RunDLL command being issued but I can't find out what.

Does anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's the equivalent of using START.

If you try

```
START http://www.google.com
```

from the command line (or a batch file), it should work fine.

Comment: There he goes, pushing his search engine again... :P

Comment: (Yes, I know Jan planted it, but other googling software is available...)

Comment: If I were truly pushing "my" search engine I'd have changed the URL to http://askjonskeet.com :)

Comment: That actually popped into my head at the time of commenting, but daven't enough coffee on board to integrate a ref to it...

Answer (score 0):

What Jon said appears to be correct. I tested it with mailto:someone@somewhere.com. Interestingly if you wish to make run work like the default behaviour of cmd, you can do the following:

Start -> Run -> cmd /c http://www.google.com. Not sure why anyone would ever need to do that though!